# No wifi connection blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, httpconnection

I want to download data using HttpConnection , see the example below

```
  class ConnectionThread extends Thread
      {
       public void run()
        {
    try{

    showToast("in the run method");
    HttpConnection conn = null;
    String URL = "http://xxxxxxx.com/api/api.php?func=showAllCountries;interface=wifi";
    conn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(URL);

    }catch(Exception e){
        showToast(e+"");


    }
    }
```

while running above code , on simulator it says Java.io.IOException  No Wi-Fi connection found , Though in manage connection i can see simultor is conncted with Wifi ,
please why this is happening

Please

Comment: Check this, `The BlackBerry Simulators do not support Wi-Fi connections.` !, http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=12151&query.id=401922#M12151

Answer (score 1):

use `deviceside= false;`

in simulator wifi is not possible, simulator will access your system network , once you are on real device wifi will work if it is enabled in device.

[Follow this link on how to make connections.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879)